# How do I compile and install a Cydia app?

Tags: windows, cydia

I have downloaded iSwipe from Cydia and I really like it, but it lacks a dictionary of italian words. I have found [the original github repository](https://github.com/wyndwarrior/iSwipe) of iSwipe and it gives access to the code.

I would like to modify it to allow for the use of multiple languages, but I have never programmed any iPhone apps nor I know how to compile them and run them as Cydia apps.

Apart from forking the repository and modifying the code to my fit my needs, which I know how to do, could anybody kindly guide me through the process of compiling it and installing it on my phone to test it?

I am using Windows and don't have access to an OS X workstation, is it still possible?

P.S.: if this is the wrong site for this question, please move it. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the stack overflow site. You'll want to research that site to get a feel for what they consider good questions before posting a basic how to I press the compile button in Xcode, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install iFile for your iPhone/iPod/iPad/whatever(the free version will do) and navigate to /var/mobile/Wynd/Swype . There you can find the dictionary and you can edit however you want.

Now I have a question for you, where will you find the complete dictionary of words? :)

Comment: That is not a problem, I had already found the swype dictionary and downloaded a full copy of the italian dictionary, but then I realized that the best solution would be to try and make iSwipe read from the currently selected iOS dictionary. That's why I'd have to recompile.